# How do I Parallelize Data across GPUs for a defined function in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing

How do I Parallelize Data for a defined function that returns a Stochastic Operator from a modified Euler-Maruyama scheme over the first dimension (number of paths)? I've tried something like this:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class sample_NdFP():
    def __init__(self, M, T, N, Dim):
        """ Parallelization of Stochastic Sample """
        self.M = M
        self.T = T
        self.N = N
        self.Dim = Dim
    def __len__(self):
        """ Return integer representing total example number in Dataset """
        return M * N * Dim
    def __getitem__(self, idx1, idx2, idx3):
        """ Return a single sample value at index 1, 2, and 3. """
        return self._custom_sample(M, T, N, Dim)[idx1, idx2, idx3]
    def _custom_sample(self, M, T, N, Dim):
    #     l = 0.1 / np.sqrt(Dim)
        dt = T / N
        Gaussvar = np.sqrt(dt)
        arr = torch.randn(M, N, Dim)
        arr[:, 0, :] = torch.zeros((M, Dim))
        for i in range(1, N):
            mu = arr[:, i - 1, :]
            arr[:, i, :] = arr[:, i - 1, :] + mu * dt + arr[:, i, :] * Gaussvar
        return arr
```

where I call this function as

```
FPsample = sample_NdFP._custom_sample(M0, T, N, Dim)
X_rand0 = DataLoader(FPsample, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=torch.cuda.device_count())
```

but that doesn't seem to work. All help is greatly appreciated!!
Thank you.

I tried using `DataLoader()` to parallelize my function to no avail. I'm not sure how I would integrate it into a neural network, or I would use `DataParallel()` instead.

Comment: DataLoader by itself does not parallelize across GPUs, it's task for Distributed Data Parallel (DDP). So I would suggest looking at this direction, and aside from information in torch documentation, have look at this simplified example: https://gist.github.com/sgraaf/5b0caa3a320f28c27c12b5efeb35aa4c

Comment: @draw Would that work to parallelize the program class `sample_NdFP()`, specifically the `_custom_sample(self, M, T, N, Dim)` code? Everything else is secondary.

Comment: So you actually want to parallelize computation of tensor named `arr` in `_custom_sample`? One GPU would be fast enough for such operations, question only about size. May you provide some info: what are typical values of M, N and Dim? (just orders of magnitude would be enough) And also: do you really want to return in `__getitem__` just one value from big `arr`? (all this computation just for one value?)

Comment: @draw Really, `__getitem__` is only there because I was mimicking code I found online exemplifying how to parallelize code in Pytorch. `N = 1350`, `Dim = 1000`, and `M` which is the dimension I would like to parallelize ideally, is `M = 8000`. Every 500 epochs, before I call my Neural Network, I call this function with 8000 as M.

Comment: What's the goal for parallelizing this function? Could you not just use `torch.multiprocessing`?

Comment: @Djinn I'm not sure how to use it with GPUs.

Comment: How to use what with GPUs? If you're referring to Pytorch, it automatically uses CUDA-enabled GPUs. If you're referring to multiprocessing, you would assign the GPU per child process using `torch.device("cuda:i")`, where `i` is the specific GPU identifier.